# ! Undefined control sequence. - no idea where the error is

Tags: beamer

I hope someone will bother to deal with my very basic problem - When trying to compile the code displayed below I get the error message

```
"! Undefined control sequence.

l.70 \@w"
```

I read through similar problems, where the answers suggest that the second line of the above error message is supposed to give me a hint, but I have no clue what \@w could be.

Btw. I'm using MikTeX with WinEdt on Windows 7 Professional, if that matters.

Thanks very much for any help
B

```
\documentclass[t,10pt,noamsthm,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},pdflatex]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newcommand{\sprache}{englisch}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\PassOptionsToPackage{cmyk}{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{sansmathaccent}
\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\title{(working title)}

\author{Author}
\date{August 25, 2014, Place}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}[body]%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[body]%

\setbeamertemplate{headline}[title]%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[title]%


\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{spacing}{1.1}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}[body]%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[body]%


\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Contents}
\vspace*{1pt}%
\hspace*{2pt}\parbox[t]{100mm}{%
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\tableofcontents
\end{spacing}
}%
\end{frame}


\section{Hello}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Hi
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{spacing}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}[final]%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[final]%

\begin{frame}
\usebeamertemplate{final page}%
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The exact same code runs on (still) TL 2013.

Comment: This code runs without problems on TeXLive 2014

Comment: You can always check what a command does with for instance `\show\title`. If the command contains an `@` which is used as a "letter" of a macro, use `\makeatletter\show\@w\makeatother`.

Comment: Your error message appears incomplete, is that really all that is in the log? (It does not have the right format: it should have a context line showing the undefined command). The posted code runs without error, check it does at your site: copy the text into a new file and process with latex. If your original document makes an error it is elsewhere.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error that's insufficiently documented and apparently cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

The same code runs on MiKTeX 2.9 (windows 8). 
Works with Latex->PDF and LuaLaTex -> PDF commands. But not with XeLaTex->PDF
Line no.70 and 71 remain as blank lines. 
Try once again by removing the blank lines. Perhaps this may not be the real reason.